# what kind of x fits into argsort(x) == argsort(argsort(x))?

Tags: numpy, sorting

For a 1-d array, what kind of x gives you `argsort(x) == argsort(argsort(x))` ? sorted array would be a trivial soliton.
but you can have not sorted array like `[1, 0, 2]` or `[1, 0, 2, 3]`

i'm really interested.

```py
sorted_array = np.arange(10)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(sorted_array), np.argsort(np.argsort(sorted_array)))

# or
semi_sorted = [1, 0, 2]
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(semi_sorted), np.argsort(np.argsort(semi_sorted)))

# or 

semi_sorted = [1, 0, 2, 3]

np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(semi_sorted), np.argsort(np.argsort(semi_sorted)))

# or

semi_sorted = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]

np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(semi_sorted), np.argsort(np.argsort(semi_sorted)))
```

what type of arrays fits in the criteria?

Comment: Interesting question, but it seems to be more about mathematics than programming. Perhaps math.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask?

Comment: good idea, let me post it there.

Comment: Conjecture: a permutation of `x = np.arange(n)` must have all its permutation cycles of maximum length 2 in order to satisfy `np.argsort(x) == np.argsort(np.argsort(x))`.

Comment: my guess is actually something like this, 1, arrays have single direction increase/decrease,  (which is sorted) 2, arrays can change direction, but make sure, when direction changes, the minimum/maximum is bigger/smaller than the maximum/minimum of the previous direction.

Comment: So to check I understand, would `x = [4, 5, 3, 2, 0, 1]` satisfy your (2)? Incidently the permutation cycles for `x` here are `[[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3]]` and it satisfied the `argsort` criteria.

Answer (score 1):

To formalize @Alex Riley's intuition:

For any (zero based) permutation p we have argsort(p) = p^-1 because by definition of argsort p[argsort(p)] = [0,1,2,...] and [0,1,2,...] viewed as a permutation is the identity.

Now, no matter what x, argsort(x) is a permutation, so writing p for that we get p = p^-1 or, equivalently, p^2 = id.

What do permutations p that are self-inverse look like? If p is applied twice nothing changes, so if the first application of p moves x to y the second application of p must move y to x. As y may equal x p must therefore consist of flips of two elements and of elements that stay put. That is also sufficient.

We now know what argsort(x) looks like. What about x itself? Let us for simplicity assume x has only unique elements, otherwise the details of the sort algorithm used have to be considered. Let us write s for the sorted x. Then s = x[p]. Permuting both sides with p we get s[p] = x[p^2] = x. So x may be any sequence that is obtained from an ordered sequence by flipping the positions of some (possibly zero) nonoverlapping pairs.